# jquery variable outside function

Tags: jquery, function, variables

How can I update a variable outside of a function? For example I have this:

```
        var max_index = 0;

    //loop through the z-index's
    $(".widget_container").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("z-index") > max_index){
            max_index = $(this).attr("z-index") + 1;
        }
    });

    alert(max_index);
```

The only problem with this is that `max_index` is always alerting `0`. How can I have that update the `max_index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can update the variable, it's accessible from the outer [closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html), the problem is that *`z-index` is not an attribute*, it is a **CSS** property, you can get it using the jQuery [css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) function:

```
    var max_index = 0;

    //loop through the z-index's
    $(".widget_container").each(function(){
      if($(this).css('zIndex') > max_index){
        max_index = +$(this).css('zIndex') + 1;
      }
    });

    alert(max_index);
```

Notice that I use a plus sign before the addition, that is the unary plus operator, it converts the `zIndex` value to number, since this function returns strings, and if one of the operands of the `+` operator is a string, a concatenation is done ( `"0" + 1 = "01"` ).

Also note that the CSS properties that contain dashes, like `background-color` or `font-size`, are accessed removing the dash, and capitalizing the next word.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$(this).attr("z-index")
```

should be

```
$(this).css("z-index")
```

This returns a string

Use:

```
parseInt($(this).css("z-index"))
```